# Monotonic convergence of Newton's method for boundary value problems

Tags: pde, reference-request, nonlinear-equations, newton-method, elliptic-pde

I’m interested in solving nonlinear elliptic boundary value problems of the type
$$
-a\Delta u + f(u) = 0,
$$
$$
u|_\Gamma = u_0
$$
by Newton’s method when its convergence is global and monotonic.
Could you advice some references concerning this problem, containing proofs of global convergence?

Newton's method takes the form
$$
-a\Delta u + f(\widetilde u) + f'(\widetilde u)(u - \widetilde u) = 0
$$
where $\widetilde u$ is the previous approximation for the solution.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1359092/11268 Please don't post multiple versions of your question on different SE sites, and if a question might suit multiple sites, pick the one most likely to generate a helpful answer. FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Comment: Also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/211385/.